# How to make the damage inflicted to the enemy and the main character more unpredictable

Tags: unity, mobile

I am developing a small mobile game. The enemy can damage my player by throwing objects at his side, and the player can damage the enemy by hitting him with a bat.

For the moment, I am calculating the damage that was caused by the player or the enemy in a very simple way. For example, my enemy has 100% of health. When the player hits him with a bat, the enemy is losing 10% of his health. So after 10 hits the enemy is "dead".

But this is not interesting. The game process is very simple and predictable: you are moving, see the enemy, hit him 10 times, and the move to the next enemy. When the enemy hits the player,the player loses 10% of his  health. That is not cool (the game process is very static).

An alternative, is to use random integer values to calculate damage values. Can anyone give an idea, how to make damage process more interactive and unpredictable, and how to make proportional link between player health and enemy health and the damage.

Comment: What are you using to create your game?

Comment: Oh, i am sorry, i didn't mention this fact. I am using Unity2d game engine.

Comment: You should be able to use the random object to create a range of which you can roll a value.  In c# the context would be Random rng = new Random();
int RollValue = rng.Next(1,10);
where 1 is the lowest value and 10 the highest
you can roll whatever range you want.
Additionally you could do someething like this : 
int RollValue = rng.Next(1 + heroDamage, 10 + heroDamage);
In this way you can increase damage based on variables.

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about it. But, to my mind this is also not very dynamic and unpredictable. How to prevent the situation, when the player never can kill the enemy (for example, my player has 10% of health, and the enemy has 100% of health). May be in this case i have to create some kind of connection between the player's health, the health of the enemy and the percentage of the damage,

Comment: That is why you define a Minimum Value for the Random function.  If you give it a range of 10-20, the minimum roll is 10. Thus ensuring you will always have a value being deducted from the Player's health.  It sounds like you need to decide if you want static or random.  You are saying that you don't like the 10% every time, but also you are saying the random is unpredictable:P

Comment: "heroDamage" is an integer value of current players health? Sorry to introduce you astray, but I confused myself today, choosing a suitable algorithm for the damage)))

Comment: Yes I used it as an example.  It could be any variable you choose to incoroporate into your game.  What happens if you choose to allow your character to upgrade his bat?  In this way you can use whatever your bat(weapon) damage is, and add it to your random function.  Also I would calculate using integers, opposed to percentages.

Comment: Also, why do you want to relate the damage to the opposing objects health?  How does this come into play in your game mechanics?

Comment: "Also, why do you want to relate the damage to the opposing objects health?" - Hmm, i don't know, it was the first thing i thought about. Okay, I'll try to use random variables with my specific variable. Thank you,  Shroeder!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are entirely design considerations and there's many ways to go about this. For starters:

1. Instead of strict damage, give it a range. ie. the bat doesn't do "10 damage", instead make it do 8-12 and randomize it between those values.
2. Give the enemy a chance to dodge or the player a chance to miss based upon some small percentage. This must be reflected visually (and audibly?) somehow.
3. Give the enemy/player a chance to crit for 2x or 3x damage.

If desired (and fitting within your design) the player may be given the ability to "upgrade" any of these through the actual weapon or skill.

For the second part of your question regarding linking the player's health that would entirely need to make sense within your design. One example would be that as a character's health is reduced their attacks get weaker. The other side to that coin could be that as a character's health is reduced adrenaline kicks in and their attacks get stronger. It all depends on how you want to spin it and that the mechanic makes some sense as opposed to being arbitrary.